# how can I calculate how much storage existing kudu table actually uses

Tags: cloudera, impala, apache-kudu

I would like to calculate how big (in GB) existing kudu table actually it.
Does anybody know how to do this  ?

Answer (score 1):

Only way that I'm aware of to do this is to collect said metrics over http against the individual tablet servers.

Example call: `curl -s 'http://tserver.host:8050/metrics?include_schema=1&metrics=on_disk_size'`

You can pull those metrics and work from there.